# Does Google Cloud Bigtable support transparent maintenance / live migrations?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable

Google [Cloud Bigtable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/) availability is currently only within [zones](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/zones), not regions.

Does Cloud Bigtable support [transparent maintenance / live migrations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/zones#maintenance) to another zone within a region?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do transparent maintenance "updates" on Cloud Bigtable. However, if a zone goes down for whatever reason, we don't automatically move you to another zone. We are planning on releasing a replication option which should be used for mission critical services and which can be used to increase the effective availability of your application.

More details will come out as we get closer to launching our replication functionality.

Comment: Hi Les - In the early days of GCE, Google would schedule zone maintenance dates so you had to manually move / replicate your servers to another zone. Once Google released transparent maintence / live migrations, I let it fall off my radar and haven't kept up with the nuances of it -- does Google still schedule to take zones offline, and if so, are you saying in this case, Cloud BigTable migration to another zone will be handled transparently?

Comment: For planned maintenance and upgrades will always try to keep the Zone active to the extent possible.  A zone may become unavailable due to unplanned emergencies, however.